# DHCP - Force install routing table to local computer

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, dhcp

I would like to use my Ubuntu VM to act as a dhcp server and gateway for my work laptop,

This laptop must connect to a Cisco anyconnect SSLVPN in order to access internal resources This VPN is not a split tunneling, which means that all the laptop's traffic is encrypted and go through the tunnel to VPN server

Is there a way to configure my ubuntu or a Kali linux on it's dhcp server to force install a specific routing table which tells the laptop to use split tunnel the traffic, in other words I will specify only some IP subnets to be routed through the tunnel interface but the default gateway (0.0.0.0/32) must exit directly through my linux, so I guess we could play with the metric so it can be lower the the VPN default route's metric.

As far as I know there are some Firewalls that can do this option but not on the DHCP server itself. Since the only weapon I have got is a Ubuntu VM or Kali linux VM.

The reason I want to do this because my work laptop is administratively locked so I have no privilege access to change it's network configuration.

Thank you,

Comment: *"on it's dhcp server"* - which dhcp server specifically? Are you envisaging having multiple DHCP servers in the same network since you state that you want to use your Ubuntu VM as a DHCP server for your laptop, suggests so

Comment: Yes, I will be configuring the dhcp server on the ubuntu VM so it can give ip addressing to my laptop, but I wander if there is an option on the ubuntu to force send a specific routes to the laptop instead of just normal default gateway

Comment: you've failed to answer either question in my comment ... you keep saying *"the dhcp server"* like there's only one DHCP server software ... and ... will this be the ONLY DHCP server in that network segment?

Comment: My home router is a DHCP server for my LAN but I don't want to use it for my work laptop, so I want my ubuntu to act as another router with DHCP server and NAT to send the laptop's traffic where I want it to go, I hope you got my point now

Comment: sure, but what DHCP server (the software, what is it called)are you planning on running on the VM - and how do you plan on making sure the laptop uses that instead of the main router DHCP

Comment: Just back to my important question :) , Do you know how to configure this DHCP option to force the ubuntu install a routing table to the laptop ?

Comment: To divert you again from your question. Did you check if [`openconnect`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/openconnect) could be used as replacement? As it offers a NetworkManager plugin it can then be used quite easily for split tunnel.

Comment: Thank you !!! This is what I have been looking for, a package that has a networking functionality, I will try it out.

Comment: *`Just back to my important question`* - sure, because I have no reason to ask which DHCP server software you're using ... *`Do you know how to configure this DHCP option....`* yes, I do, depending on **which DHCP server software you are using**